# Matlab "system" command stuck

Tags: matlab, operating-system

I am using matlab to automatically parameter and launch a finite element method code. I write a parameter text file that the FEM code will read, and then call for the FEM code with :

```
[status,cmdout]=system(['FEMApp ' current_folder '\MyFile']);
```

Sometimes, the FEM App will be unable to complete its task, and send an error message in the command window. Until now, I was able to detect the error message in cmdout, and proceed to the next paramter set.

For an unknown reason, the system command started to behave differently : it gets stuck for seemingly forever (Matlab is always in "busy" mode). Did I change anything without realizing it ?

For now, I am using the following solution :

```
[status,cmdout]=system(['FEMApp ' current_folder '\MyFile &']);
pause(45)
system(['taskkill' 'FEMProcessus')
```

It works correctly, but it slows my computation a lot (~ x5), because Matlab will always wait 45 secondes even when the task is completed in much less time.

Can anyone explain the change in behaviour of Matlab ?
Does anyone has a cleverer work around than mine ?

Answer (score -2):

It should be noted that Matlab is an *interpreter* rather than a compiler. That means it performs a lot of internal operations, hidden from the developer, some of which may require a lot of CPU resources. Finite Element applications are very numerically intense in terms of using CPU and RAM resources. It might not be a good idea to use Matlab for FEM programming. Try to use some numerically-oriented language, like C or Fortran, where you will have full control over memory allocation and arithmetic operations.